# SwiftUI: how to update a variable transiting from a parent view only when wanted?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I would like to pass a variable from a parent to a child view, but in this child view, use it in a text field but update this value only when a SAVE button is pressed.

I tried this:

**ParentView**

```
struct ParentView: View {
    @State private var name: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("User name: \(name)")
            Spacer()
            NavigationLink(
                destination: ChildView(name: name),
                label: {
                    Text("Update name")
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**ChildView**

```
struct ChildView: View {
    @State private var name: String = ""
    @Binding var passedName: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form {
                TextField("Update name", text: $name)
                Button(action: {
                    passedName = name
                }, label: {
                    Text("SAVE")
                })
            }
        }
    }
    
    init(name: String) {
        self._passedName = .constant(name)
        self.name = name
    }        
}
```

Since I don't want to update the variable directly, I tried to use a `name` value and then only set the value of the binded `passedName` when the OK button is tapped. But it doesn't work.

I don't know how to do what I want to.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your general approach is correct - have a state variable to represent a temporarily typed name, but a binding to represent the name "returned" to the parent.

Because the child modifies the data owned by the parent, it needs to accept a binding - not a plain `String`:

```
struct ChildView: View {
    @State private var name: String
    @Binding var passedName: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form {
                TextField("Update name", text: $name)
                Button(action: {
                    passedName = name
                }, label: {
                    Text("SAVE")
                })
            }
        }
    }

    init(name: Binding<String>) {
        self._passedName = name
        self._name = State(initialValue: name.wrappedValue)
    }
}
```

Then, pass in a binding from the parent:

```
ChildView(name: $name)
```

Comment: Almost... you still need init to give `tempName` initial value from `name`.

Comment: @Asperi, I thought about that, but in the OP's question he just set it to `""`, so I didn't want to add my own interpretation. EDIT: Never mind..  he did attempt to change it in `init`... Will update the answer

Comment: Thank you very much, I got it working and understood. Could you also explain me why I need to initialize `_name` with `State(initialValue: name.wrappedValue)` instead of only `self.name = name.wrappedValue` in ChildView's `init?` What's the difference?

Comment: @AnotherDude, that would result in `Variable 'self.name' used before being initialized`, and if you initialize it with `""`, then it would overwrite `name.wrappedValue` set in `init`... give it a try

Comment: Thank you again. I think I'll ask a separate question about this because I still need some insight - declarative programming and state are still an obscure thing to me.